# cookiecutter-django docker-compose -f production.yml up hangs

Tags: django, docker, cookiecutter-django

I created a cookiecutter-django app and left it pretty much pain vanilla. Except because I need to run on EC2, behind and Elastic Load Balancer with an SSL cert from AWS Certificate manager, I need to use nginx instead of Caddy.

Here's my production.yml:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
  postgres_backup: {}

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx/Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: pulsemanager_production_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
      - ./.env
    command: /gunicorn.sh

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: pulsemanager_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2
```

Here's my .env file:

```
# General
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=randomdjangosecretkey
DJANGO_ADMIN_URL=djangoadminurl/
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=.pulse.example.com

# Security
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TIP: better off using DNS, however, redirect is OK too
DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False

# Email
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_MAILGUN_API_KEY=randommailgunkey
DJANGO_SERVER_EMAIL=randomserver@gmail.com
MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN=mg.example.com

# AWS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=randomawskeyid
DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=randomawssecretkey
DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=pulsemanager

# django-allauth
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION=True

# Gunicorn
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEB_CONCURRENCY=4

# Sentry
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_SENTRY_DSN=randomsentrydsn


# Redis
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0

# PostgreSQL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=pulsemanager
POSTGRES_USER=randouserid
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=randompassword

# Caddy
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOMAIN_NAME=pulse.example.com


docker-compose -f production.yml up
```

works fine.

```
docker-compose -f production.yml up
```

might be mostly working, but I can't tell. I'm getting a lot of warnings and at then it seems like redis is running, but the "up command" never completes. Meaning, I never get my cursor back.

Also trying access access the EC2 instance via it's IP or dns name gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Here's my security group:

```
Security Groups 
Ports   Protocol    Source  MNNSecurityGroup
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
8000    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
2376    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
```

Here's the output from my "up command":

````
MacBook-Pro-de-Brad:pulsemanager bradrhoads$ docker-compose -f production.yml up
Starting pulsemanager_redis_1      ... done
Recreating pulsemanager_postgres_1 ... done
Recreating pulsemanager_django_1   ... done
Recreating pulsemanager_nginx_1    ... done
Attaching to pulsemanager_redis_1, pulsemanager_postgres_1, pulsemanager_django_1, pulsemanager_nginx_1
redis_1     | 1:C 17 May 12:31:38.287 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
postgres_1  | 2018-05-17 12:31:39.377 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
django_1    | PostgreSQL is up - continuing...
redis_1     |                 _._
redis_1     |            _.-``__ ''-._
redis_1     |       _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.2.11 (00000000/0) 64 bit
redis_1     |   .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
redis_1     |  (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
redis_1     |  |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
redis_1     |  |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 1
redis_1     |   `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
redis_1     |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
redis_1     |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
redis_1     |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
redis_1     |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
redis_1     |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
redis_1     |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
redis_1     |       `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
redis_1     |           `-._        _.-'
redis_1     |               `-.__.-'
redis_1     |
postgres_1  | 2018-05-17 12:31:39.377 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
django_1    | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py:91: UserWarning: Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.
django_1    |   warnings.warn('Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.')
redis_1     | 1:M 17 May 12:31:38.291 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
postgres_1  | 2018-05-17 12:31:39.380 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
django_1    | Copying '/app/pulsemanager/static/js/project.js'
redis_1     | 1:M 17 May 12:31:38.291 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.11
postgres_1  | 2018-05-17 12:31:39.398 UTC [19] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-05-17 04:16:55 UTC
django_1    | Copying '/app/pulsemanager/static/images/favicons/favicon.ico'
redis_1     | 1:M 17 May 12:31:38.292 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
postgres_1  | 2018-05-17 12:31:39.421 UTC [19] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
django_1    | Copying '/app/pulsemanager/static/sass/custom_bootstrap_vars.scss'
redis_1     | 1:M 17 May 12:31:38.292 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
django_1    | Copying '/app/pulsemanager/static/sass/project.scss'
django_1    | Copying '/app/pulsemanager/static/css/project.css'
postgres_1  | 2018-05-17 12:31:39.424 UTC [19] LOG:  redo starts at 0/16348A0
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/core.js'
postgres_1  | 2018-05-17 12:31:39.424 UTC [19] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/16348D8: wanted 24, got 0
redis_1     | 1:M 17 May 12:31:38.292 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
postgres_1  | 2018-05-17 12:31:39.424 UTC [19] LOG:  redo done at 0/16348A0
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/prepopulate_init.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/inlines.min.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/urlify.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/calendar.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/cancel.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/prepopulate.min.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/timeparse.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/change_form.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/collapse.min.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/collapse.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/autocomplete.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/actions.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/actions.min.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/popup_response.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/SelectBox.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/inlines.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/LICENSE-JQUERY.txt'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/LICENSE-XREGEXP.txt'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.min.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/LICENSE-SELECT2.md'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/tr.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pl.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/uk.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/th.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sr-Cyrl.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ro.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/gl.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hi.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/is.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/km.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pt-BR.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/az.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/it.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pt.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/lv.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sv.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/fa.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hr.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/el.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/mk.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/es.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ca.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sk.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/nl.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ja.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/de.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hu.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/fi.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/lt.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/vi.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/zh-TW.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ar.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/en.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/he.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/zh-CN.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/da.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/nb.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/eu.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ru.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/bg.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/id.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/et.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/fr.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sr.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ko.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/cs.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ms.js'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/forms.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/changelists.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/widgets.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/login.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/fonts.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/responsive.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/rtl.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/dashboard.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/autocomplete.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/responsive_rtl.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.min.css'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/vendor/select2/LICENSE-SELECT2.md'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-clock.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/LICENSE'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-unknown-alt.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-changelink.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/inline-delete.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/README.txt'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-calendar.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/calendar-icons.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/search.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/selector-icons.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/tooltag-arrowright.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-deletelink.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/sorting-icons.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-alert.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/tooltag-add.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-unknown.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-no.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/gis/move_vertex_off.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/gis/move_vertex_on.svg'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/fonts/LICENSE.txt'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/fonts/README.txt'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff'
django_1    | Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff'
django_1    | 123 static files copied.
django_1    | [2018-05-17 12:31:53 +0000] [266] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.8.1
django_1    | [2018-05-17 12:31:53 +0000] [266] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (266)
django_1    | [2018-05-17 12:31:53 +0000] [266] [INFO] Using worker: sync
django_1    | [2018-05-17 12:31:53 +0000] [269] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 269
django_1    | [2018-05-17 12:31:53 +0000] [274] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 274
django_1    | [2018-05-17 12:31:53 +0000] [276] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 276
django_1    | [2018-05-17 12:31:53 +0000] [282] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 282
django_1    | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py:91: UserWarning: Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.
django_1    |   warnings.warn('Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.')
django_1    | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py:91: UserWarning: Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.
django_1    |   warnings.warn('Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.')
django_1    | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py:91: UserWarning: Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.
django_1    |   warnings.warn('Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.')
redis_1     | 1:M 17 May 12:31:38.292 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
redis_1     | 1:M 17 May 12:36:39.042 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
redis_1     | 1:M 17 May 12:36:39.043 * Background saving started by pid 13
redis_1     | 13:C 17 May 12:36:39.048 * DB saved on disk
redis_1     | 13:C 17 May 12:36:39.048 * RDB: 6 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
````

Are the various warnings things I need to worry about? How can I isolate what's working and what's not?

Any other help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had ALLOWED_HOSTS set to my production domain name, instead of this new EC2 instance IP address.

Just for the record, even after making that fix, the "up command" didn't seem to complete. But it actually did.

Onward and upward!